# Python: Error al importar mutuamente modulos

Tags: python, python-3.x, mvc, python-import

Soy novato en POO, aunque ya manejo la mayoría de los conceptos básicos. Estoy desarrollando un sistema en Python 3 que básicamente es un CRUD. Estoy implementando una arquitectura por capas MVC (Modelo - Vista - Controlador), y actualmente tengo una clase **Vista** (Vista), una clase **Trabajador** (Modelo), y **Controlador** (Controlador). El problema surge al importar mutuamente los módulos:

```
Python
#modulo Controlador
try:
    import Trabajador
except ImportError as e:
    print('Error: ', e)

try:
    import vista
except ImportError as e:
    print('Error: ', e)



#Modulo Trabajador
try:
    import controlador
except ImportError as e:
    print('Error: ', e)


#Modulo Vista
try:
    import controlador
except ImportError as e:
    print('Error: ', e)
```

Al ejecutar el modulo Controlador (en donde se instancian todas las demas clases y se corre el programa), me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Python

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "controlador.py", line 2, in <module>
        import trabajador
    File "C:\Users\Martin Villablanca\Desktop\Programa\trabajador.py", line 2, in <module>
        import controlador
    File "C:\Users\Martin Villablanca\Desktop\Programa\controlador.py", line 107, in <module>
        app.genesis()
    File "C:\Users\Martin Villablanca\Desktop\Programa\controlador.py", line 41, in genesis
        miTrabajador = trabajador.Trabajador(genesis.cedula_trabajador, genesis.nombre_trabajador, genesis.apellido_trabajador)
    AttributeError: module 'trabajador' has no attribute 'Trabajador'
```

Answer (score 4):

Estas cayendo en un típico problema de dependencias cíclicas, de imports cíclicos concretamente.

Simplificando podemos reproducir tu problema:

### controlador.py

```
import trabajador

class App:
    def genesis(self):
        trabajador.Trabajador()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = App()
    app.genesis()
```

### trabajador.py

```
import controlador

class Trabajador:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Trabajador instanciado")
```

Si ejecutamos `controlador.py` (que no es lo mismo que importarlo) nos encontramos con el mencionado error:

> ```
> $ py3 controlador.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "controlador.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import trabajador
>   File "/trabajador.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import controlador
>   File "/controlador.py", line 9, in <module>
>     app.genesis()
>   File "/controlador.py", line 5, in genesis
>     trabajador.Trabajador()
> AttributeError: module 'trabajador' has no attribute 'Trabajador'
> ```

Cuando se importa un módulo, Python busca si ya ha cargado dicho módulo en el diccionario `sys.modules`, el cual guarda las referencias a los objetos de cada módulo importado. Si no lo encuentra ejecuta el módulo, creando el objeto en memoria y agregando una referencia a `sys.modules`.

- En nuestro ejemplo, ejecutamos `controlador.py`, el cual en la primera línea importa el módulo `trabajador`.
- Como `trabajador` no está cargado, lo ejecuta. `trabajador` a su vez importa a `controlador` en la primera línea.
- Al no haber sido importado `controlador` antes  (se ejecutó como módulo principal, pero no se ha importado nunca), se ejecuta desde el principio. Lo primero que se encuentra es con `import trabajador`. Como este módulo ya fue importado obtiene la referencia al mismo simplemente. El problema es que `trabajador` no llegó a cargarse completamente porque el propio import de `controlador` dejó bloqueada temporalmente su ejecución en ese punto.
- Al no haberse llegado a cargar `trabajador` completamente, cuando la ejecución causada por el import de controlador llega a `app.genesis()` se encuentra que `trabajador.Trabajador` nunca llegó definirse y tenemos el error.

Para el ejemplo anterior, bastaría con hacer que las dos últimas líneas solo se ejecuten cuando `controlador.py` se ejecute como módulo principal y no cuando sea importado:

```
import trabajador

class App:
    def genesis(self):
        trabajador.Trabajador()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = App()
    app.genesis()
```

> ```
> $ py3 controlador.py
> Trabajador instanciado
> ```

Ésta no tiene por que ser la solución en tu caso, habría que ver el resto de tu código y la estructura de tu app.

Por norma general, **los imports cíclicos indican un error en el diseño**. Hay veces en las que es muy fácil solucionarlo, por ejemplo retrasando el import o importando dentro del método o función que lo necesite, pero otras veces el problema es más profundo y requiere reestructurar buena parte de la aplicación.