# Cannot import name (...) from partially initialized module

Tags: python, django, django-models

llevo poco tiempo en esto de Python y estoy intentando hacer un proyecto en el cual me da este error y no sé cómo avanzar. ¡Necesito ayuda! :( Gracias de antemano.

Os adjunto imagen de los dos modelos y el error en consola:

```
from django.db import models from adopcion.models import Persona

# Create your models here.

 class Vacuna(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Mascota(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    edad_aproximada = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_rescate = models.DateTimeField()
```

```
persona=models.ForeignKey(Persona,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
vacuna = models.ManyToManyField(Vacuna, blank=True)
```

```
from django.db import models
from mascotas.models import Vacuna,Mascota

class Persona(models.Model):
    'folio = models.CharField(max_length=10 primary_key=True'
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    edad = models.IntegerField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField()
    domicilio = models.TextField()
```

ERROR DE LA CMD:

> from mascota.models import Vacuna,Mascota ImportError: cannot import
>   name 'Vacuna' from partially initialized module 'mascota.models'

Comment: Hola Esther, bienvenida a [es.so]. Importas los módulos mutuamente, cayendo en imports/dependencias circulares. La solución en el 99% de los casos es reestructurar la app para que los módulos no tengan que importarse mutuamente. Por cierto, ¿para que importas `Vacuna` y `Mascota` en `adopcion`? Aparentemente no los usas para nada (al menos en el código mostrado) y en cambio está causando el problema de importación cíclica...

Comment: Mirate  esta pregunta: [Python: Error al importar mutuamente modulos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/260031/15089)